# Redirect an old URL structure to new URL structure?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, permalinks

I need to have URL's from an old structure redirect to a new structure.

Old URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=28341&highlight=inner#28341
```

New URL:

```
http://domain.com/viewtopic.php?p=28341&highlight=inner#28341
```

How can I do this via htaccess? Or do I need to add something to /index.php file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the parameter `name` used at all?

Comment: The name variable is no longer being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?name=[^&]*&file=viewtopic&p=([^&]+)&highlight=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /viewtopic.php?p=%1&highlight=%2#%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```